# Help me translate the C++ code to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, transactions, equivalent

im having hardtime in memset and memcpy. can somebody trasnlate this for me, or suggestion on how this thing work?

```
do{
  memset(szSpeechBuf, 0x0, sizeof(char)*QSIZE);
  if((nBufIter+1)*QSIZE > nRawBufLen)
    {
      diff = nRawBufLen - (nBufIter)*QSIZE;

      if(diff < 0)
      {
        printf("DetectSpeech() error : timeout!!!");
        exit(1);
      }
      memcpy(szSpeechBuf, szRawBuf+(QSIZE*nBufIter), diff);
    }
  else
    memcpy(szSpeechBuf, szRawBuf+(QSIZE*nBufIter), sizeof(char)*QSIZE);
} while(1);

// where szSpeechBuf: PAnsiChar; nBufIter: Integer; Const QSIZE = 3200
```

Comment: -1: This is not a *help-me*, this is a *do-it-for-me*. Show us what you have tried and what specific parts are not working out for you.

Comment: Provide the sample code you have so far, and tell us then what you're having problems with.  When Space_C0wb0y said "this is a *do-it-for-me*", he meant that Stack Overflow isn't for this purpose.  It is for help, not for unpaid work.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, i follow found here http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread238270.html about memset and memcpy. it does not working. they have different parameters(memcpy).

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham, OK, Sorry about the "this is a *do-it-for-me", do you have any suggestion on what to replace the "memset and memcpy"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `memset` fills a number of bytes with the specified value. In Delphi, we use `FillChar` for this. But if the value we want to fill with is zero, you can also use the `ZeroMemory` function.
- `memcpy` copies a block of bytes from one location to another (in RAM). In Delphi, we use `Move` for this. You can also use `CopyMemory` (or the **identical** function `MoveMemory`) if you want to work with pointers instead of Delphi variables.

That is,

```
Move(a, b, n)
```

copies n bytes from the data named a to the location of b, where a and b are variables. This is equivalent to

```
CopyMemory(@b, @a, n)
```

where @a and @b are the pointers to the source and destination, respectively. (Personally, I think the latter syntax is easier to explain, in some sense. It takes two *addresses*, and after all, that is how we work with memory.)

Hence, if `p` and `q` are pointers, you can do

```
CopyMemory(q, p, n)
```

or

```
Move(p^, q^, n).
```

You might also want to know how to allocate, reallocate, and free memory on the heap in Delphi. You use the `GetMem`, `ReallocMem`, and `FreeMem` procedures, respectively.

## Working with pointers

Deplhi can be rather restrictive when it comes to pointer arithmetics. But on a 32-bit system (such as the ones running Delphi applications), a pointer is really just a 32-bit unsigned integer, that is, a `cardinal`. So you can work with pointers just like cardinals, if you just tell the compiler to do so.

Hence, if the compiler doesn't allow

```
myPtr + 200
```

then you can do

```
cardinal(myPtr) + 200.
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply, but how can i put the "szRawBuf+(QSIZE*nBufIter)" to this parameter? it said the second parameter was a pointer. how does the 'szRawBuf + (QSIZE*nBufIter)' posible?

Comment: OK i got it. it is not posible to move(..) but the CopyMemory(..) does. thnx

Comment: @XBasic3000: If `CopyMemory(a, b, n)` works, then so does `Move(b^, a^, n)`. (But maybe you need to cast it like `Move(PSomeType(b)^, PSomeType(a)^, n`.)

Comment: Why a downvote? Please elaborate.

Comment: @XBasic3000: Glad you got the help you needed.  Can you post the code you ended up with?

Answer (score 1):

after a days of experimenting the code, i finaly got it work!

@Merlyn Morgan-Graham ask me to post the answer, then this question got closed! they said its not real? because i answerd it myself?

Comment: Nah, that looks good.  Glad you got it working :)

Comment: +1 and vote for re-open; I agree this is a real question about translating from C/C++ to Delphi.

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers, thanx. more power to you.